# Find the glb and lub of the set of real numbers in $(0, 1)$ whose decimal expansion contains only $0’s$ and $1’s$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Find the infimum and supremum of the set of real numbers in $(0, 1)$ whose decimal
expansion contains only$  0’s$ and $ 1’s$

Infimum of this set is $0$, 
Supremum should be $0.111111...$
Supremum of this set is not clear to me. Is there any specific number equivalent to $0.1111...$ which can be considered as supremum of this set. If no, then what is the supremum$?$

Comment: That's just $\frac 19$.

Comment: @lulu $\frac{1}{9} = 0.111...$, is there any way to find supremum in fraction form for such sets$?$

Comment: What do you mean?  You (correctly) remarked that $.\overline 1=\frac 19$ was the supremum of your set.  What is left to do?

Comment: I mean, what if I get 0.2222... How would I find a number in fraction form, equal to 0.222.... Without trying dividing numbers randomly$?$

Comment: You've lost me.  Are you asking how to change a repeating decimal into a fraction?  Obviously $.\overline 2=\frac 29$, and this is clearly not the sup of your set.

Comment: Yes, I was asking the process of changing repeating decimal into fraction. Maybe, it's really easy, but I can't recall it. I'll check it out on google. :) Thanks.

Comment: Short answer: if the period has length $P$ just multiply by $10^P$.  Thus if you have $S=.\overline {123}$ we have $P=3$, $10^3S=123.\overline {123}=123+S$ whence $S=\frac {123}{10^3-1}=\frac {123}{999}$.  And so on.

Comment: I got it. It was easy. Thanks.

Comment: @Mathsaddict that was a totally different question..